# Content variable in sitecore fields

Tags: content-editor, text-field

I got a scenario where i want to add variable in content say multiline text. This variable is kind of link which will be populated based on user profile. Having said that i m looking for best recommended approach so that content author or for that reason any developer in future should not delete or overlooked this variable and publish it without any checks. I may add validation for field and provide help text to deal with this. Is there any better approach to tackle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the modules already available for this.

https://jeffdarchuk.com/2015/10/26/sitecore-tokenmanager/

Context from what the link covers:

> TokenManager preview
>
> It’s been a while since my last blog post, that’s because I’ve been working hard on a sitecore extension.  I’m in the process of working out the last bugs but here’s a preview of what it will be capable of.
>
> Where is it used?
>
> It is found in the Telerik editor from a rich text field.
>
> what is a token?
>
> A token is a small chunk of text that is dynamically replaced with something else when the rich text field is rendered.
>
> Why use tokens?
>
> The most basic of uses is to use tokens to store common information that will change at the same time on every page, such as a customer service phone number, or address.  However I’ve devised several more use cases that the TokenManager will be able to accomplish

Comment: @anicho, thanks for this reference. Is there any feature inbuilt wherein content author don't mess with such token and would not allow to publish unless such token is missing.

Comment: Tokens are a good choice. I recently build a sitecore pipeline handler that can replace various tokens such as `{date:yyyy}` with computed values as part of the field render pipeline.

Comment: @SantoshPoojari thank ASURA for the reference. I just updated answer with more context. As for if token is missing I would recommend field validation, a custom validator can make the item unsavable and notifies the user of the problem they need to fix before they can progress.

Comment: I think it could get a bit messy. I've also done a token pipeline recently and it worked well. The tokens we added only on RTE though with a custom dropdown list. You could add validation for this but I would recommend if you do, you make it easy for the users to find or add the missing tokens.